# Original source of often used pic for deep learning

Tags: neural-networks, references

I wrote a blog post on neural networks some time ago:
https://blog.ephorie.de/understanding-the-magic-of-neural-networks

In it, I used the following pic:
[image]

It is a pic that is used quite often, with varying sources... none of which seems to be the original source.

Does anyone know who created this pic?